# asymptotic complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

suppose a computer executes one instruction in a microsecond and an algorithm is known to have a complexity of O(2^n), if a maximum of 12 hours of computer time is given to this algorithm, determine the largest possible value of n for which the algorithm can be used

Comment: This doesn't make sense. O(2^n) could mean just 2^n, but it could also mean 1000000000 * 2^n.

Comment: Could be made sensible if the givens included the N for which running time was, say, 4 hours...if there are no lower order terms dominating the shorter run time. In short this question is broken *and* hard to fix.

Comment: This sounds so much like homework. Also, please use punctuation and capitalization.

Comment: I suspect this is homework, so I outlined a method for finding the answer instead of giving the answer away.

Comment: At least have the honesty to say "I need help with this homework problem...".

Answer (score 4):

No can do.

`O(2^n)` means that there exists `C` such that `limit n->infinity f(n)<=C*(2^n)`.
But this `C` can also be the number of `023945290378569237845692378456923847569283475635463463456` so even 12 hours cannot ensure that it will run even on small input.

Comment: @Vatine not necessarily, since only the limit is guaranteed even that might take 14 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Insufficient information. An algorithm that is O(2^n) doesn't necessarily take exactly 2^n steps for input of size n, it could take a constant factor of that. In fact, it could take C*(2^n)+B operations, where C and B are constant (that is, they don't depend on n), they are are both integers, and C >= 1 and B >= 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as O(2^n) is an exponential complexity and you're asked for the "largest possible exponent", you're trying to find an N, so that 2^N is less than or equal to 12 hours (* 3600 seconds, * 1000000 for the microseconds). From there, you can either use logarithms to find the right value or estimate an initial N and iterate until you find a value.